# Send Data From PHP to VPS and Back

Tags: c#, php, html, vb.net, vps

Today I was trying to figure out how to send data from my PHP file on my host to a VPS server. I know that I need to make a a server on the VPS that will handle the data and send data back to the PHP file sending the initial request. I will make that in C# or vb.net. The server (in vb.net or c#) will listen for connections on a certain port. The problem is, I do not know how to initiate the request to the VPS in PHP. I have looked at guides online, and some of them say to use sockets and some of them say to use a TCP connection. I am  not 100% sure if those are the same thing or not. If anyone can guide me to show me what the best way of making this connection is, that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just run a webserver + php, and listen on a http port. Then in php use curl to access that port.

Socket server is not necessary, if you do not concern about performance extremely.

If you have already got a server to access from php, use socket family functions.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php will help you.